# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS randomly shuts down

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I was using ubuntu 20.04 on a notebook, but the system started to reset for no reason after a time. These shutdowns apparently did not have a clear cause, sometimes it turned off by itself (which made me think it was a hardware problem at first), but it also turned off after certain commands (such as opening the terminal, opening an app, loging in or out, abrupt CPU and RAM usage, and even when i used a specific drawing tool in the krita app, and so on). These problems were recurrent and repetitive, sometimes opening the terminal several times caused repeated shutdowns for example.

Shutdowns became more frequent until my notebook no longer works reporting not detecting the hard disk. I bought another computer thinking that my notebook problem was the hard disk, but when i reinstalled the same operating system after a while, the shutdowns and resets started again, this time there are no specific causes of software interaction as i mentioned before, it just randomly shuts down. I looked for some solutions and found several indicating different causes. I tried most of them, but I was not successful. I really have no idea what are these shutdowns and why they happen.

Comment: There should be some clues in the `/var/log/syslog` file. That will be the first place you want to look. If you see a pattern of failure messages, then you'll know what is triggering the system to shut down.

Comment: Hello. Did you use the same live media to install both of them?